# SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns - Display Title rather than key

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, spservices, cascading

I'm using SPCascadeDropdowns to filter a child drop down which is working. However, I would like to display another column than the one in the relationship.

I have created two lookup columns that 'get information from' the subdiv columns so:

Neighborhood.Subdiv => Phase.Subdiv

but when I change the parent lookup column to Neighborhood.Title, it breaks the cascade. Here is my code. Is there anyway to display the title but have it lookup the subdiv column?

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
   relationshipList: "BH_Phases",
   relationshipListParentColumn: "Subdiv",
   relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
   parentColumn: "Neighborhood",
   childColumn: "Phase",
   promptText: "Choose Phase...",
   simpleChild: true,
   debug: true
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is supported by the implementation of SPServices.  You could take the code and custize it for your own needs. Just add the column you want to the part that does the GetListItems and the use it's value when displaying the results - but remember that the <option> value attribute should reflect the correct value to save to the list.

Comment: I figured that since I couldn't find it in the documentation. I'm in the process now of doing what you suggest. I'll post my results

Comment: If you get it working and it is done in a general way (ex throught input params), then post back to the SPSercices forums and suggest it as an enhancement. Marc may consider it for a future version.